# What does “Max Supported Size” for RAM actually mean?

Tags: laptop, memory

I wantg to upgrade the RAM in an Acer Aspire 5253-BZ602.  This is what the [CNET specs page](http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-5253-bz602/specs/) says:

> Max Supported Size 8 GB

So what does that actually mean? Can I put a single 8GB RAM stick in one of the slots and leave the 2nd slot empty? Or must I put a 4GB RAM stick in each slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum supported (total) memory in that system is 8GB.  That means you can not have two 8GB SODIMMs, making 16GB of memory.  This says nothing about the *size in GB* of the SODIMMs that that the machine supports.  The size of the *individual* RAM SODIMMs is based on the memory controller.

According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-5253-bz656) (they didnt have that exact model listed, but close), that model can take up to an 8GB SODIMM, or you can put in two 4GB SODIMMs.  If you already have a 4GB installed in that laptop, just buy another 4GB SODIMM of the same type.  If you have one or two 1GB or 2GB, remove them and replace them with two 4GB SODIMMs.  Two 4GB SODIMMs are the same price as an 8GB on that page and you should get slightly more performance with two SODIMMs over one.  In addition to that, if one goes bad, then you only have to replace one and you would still have a working laptop in the meantime.

Comment: I was wanting to get the 8GB because the laptop is a bit old and I was thinking I could take that 8GB SODIMM and put it in a future laptop that might support more than 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

This mention says that the computer won't allow more memory than 8GB.

You can put any compatible memory up to 8GB (1x8GB, 2x4GB,...) depending on the number of RAM slots on the motherboard.